# Can I use a Teams app to access files in a private channel

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

There are files that I need to read and process on Teams/SharePoint. Normally, I would just use Microsoft Graph to do this. However, the big issue is that the channel that the files are in is private. I also know that I could use delegated permissions to do this. The problem is that in my web application, I am using Application permissions everywhere else I do this, and I can't mix delegated and application permissions.

I'm wondering if I can create a Teams app to act as a portal, or connector, to the files in the private channel?

I know it sounds a bit trojan horse,  but I'm assuming the Teams app would have to be authorized.

I also want to use the teams app to make the file gathering process more generic. We will have several Teams/SharePoint document libraries in the future where we will need to get the data from Excel files and aggregate it into a DB. I just want to create a generic connector of sorts that I can install in the Teams site/folder that will send my web application all the most recent files from that folder, on demand. Is that possible?

Sorry if this sounds a bit confusing, I'm treading in new waters here and not sure where to go. I know I could rely on Microsoft Graph, but the issue is that sometimes I need Application permissions, and other times I need Delegated permissions, and I can't have both in the same web application. So, my thought is to approach it from the other side and create an "inside man" so to speak, that my web application could talk to and get the most recent files from.

Comment: How come you state that you can't have both App & Delegated permissions in the same application? I'm not aware of that restriction.

Comment: Technically, I do believe it's possible. Essentially, you just need two different instances of Microsoft Graph, each instantiated differently. But, from what I have read, it's not best practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Microsoft Teams did not support direct file access for apps in private channels.